# Accessing Facebook Ads API request error 270

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

I have a whitelisted Facebook App that is out of sandbox mode and has been approved for the Ads API, but I am receiving the following error when trying to make requests to the Ads API.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#270) This Ads API request is not allowed for apps with only developer  access",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 270
   }
}
```

This occurs when using *adgroupstats*, *adcampaignstats*, and *reportstats* requests, etc. The *adaccounts* request does return my account information though. My dashboard does read *"This app is public and available to all users"*, as I needed to get out of sandbox mode in order for my app to be whitelisted.

Is there another setting that I have missed in order to gain access to the Ads API calls that I need?

Comment: Are you definitely making the API calls on behalf of one of the developers of the app?

Comment: Yes, as both a developer and administrator of the app.

Comment: If you're getting that error on behalf of an admin or developer of the app when trying to access the API on their behalf, please file a bug report - As far as I know that message should only appear if the API call comes from a user who's not an admin of the app

Comment: @Igy Fairly sure. I run the auth request with the app admin logged in, confirm, then use that code to generate the Access Token. Using that token gets me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
This is most likely due to your dev/admin accounts of the app not being set as "Admins" in facebook's ad manager. Let me know if this solves this issue for you.

Old response:
I am running into the same issue. Can not run api calls against  reportstats even though the user that the app/ad account belongs too was an admin, i change that user to a developer and its still happening.

I opened a bug report for this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786289188058999

Comment: This was essentially my issue. Setup an ad account for myself and it gives me back proper responses. Looks like now I'll have to figure out how to add a developer as an owner/admin to another account, since I'm just a developer.

Comment: Do you have access to the facebook ad manager account? You will need to ensure that the user that has access to the facebook ad manager account is admin in the ad manager, and that same user is a admin or developer of your facebook app.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. We ended up needing the ad manager account admin to go through the auth process to get his token. That token allows us the access we needed.